# Difficulty of bbl file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using Texmaker for this, and I have put in the following in the .bbl file,

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
@Article{Johnson,
author = {Edgar G. Johnson and Alfred O. Nier},
title = {Angular Aberrations in Sector Shaped Electromagnetic Lenses for Focusing Beams of 
Charged Particles},
journal = {Physical Review},
year = {1953},
volume = {91},
number = {1},
}
\end{thebibliography}
```

And here is the code for the tex file

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

....

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mp3.bbl}



\end{document}
```

but the outcome from the pdf looks like this.

@ArticleJohnson, author = Edgar G. Johnson and Alfred O. Nier, title = Angular Aberrations
in Sector Shaped Electromagnetic Lenses for Focusing Beams of Charged Particles, journal
= Physical Review, year = 1953, volume = 91, number = 1,
12

Comment: I have re-tagged the question: It is not really about `biblatex`, you are trying to use standard BibTeX, and TeXmaker is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Please, instead of adding "solved" to the question title, you should accept the useful answer by clicking the green tick below the answer score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed several things here.

A `bbl` is something else, you need with the given structure a `bib` file.

With `bibtex` you can run a `bib` file and get the result in a `bbl` file, depending on the used `\cite` commands in your `tex` file ...

To get a bibliography you have to cite at last one or more entrys. If you want to get all bib entrys cited (good for testing the `bib` file) just use command `\nocite{*}`.  To cite a special entry, for example your article `Johnson`, use `\cite{Johnson}`.

See the compiling code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Johnson,
author = {Edgar G. Johnson and Alfred O. Nier},
title = {Angular Aberrations in Sector Shaped Electromagnetic Lenses for Focusing Beams of 
Charged Particles},
journal = {Physical Review},
year = {1953},
volume = {91},
number = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} % <===================== cites all entries
\cite{Johnson} % <=============== cites entry Johnson
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}% <========= calls above bib file

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

I commented all not relevant packages you called in your code.  You tagged with `biblatex` but you didn't call it in your code.  Do you want to use `biblatex`? Then the code had to be changed a little bit ...